# how to get browser window size in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get browser window size , and set the window size to the div size in javascript.

i have 2 div elements if window size is 568px means, the div1 wants to 38% and div2 is 62%.
In every size the both div wants to maintain the same percentage size.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;
```

**UPDATE**:

To set the width of the two div elements when screen is equal or smaller than 568px you can do:

`if(width <= 568) { 
    document.getElementById('div_1').style.width = '38%';
    document.getElementById('div_2').style.width = '62%';
 }`

Or using a CSS only based solution which I think is recommended and more simpler in this case, by taking advantage of `media queries`:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
}
.div_element {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#div_1 {
  width: 38%;
  background: #adadad;
}
#div_2 {
  width: 62%;
  background: #F00;
}
@media(max-width: 568px) {
  #div_1 {
    width: 38%;
  }
  #div_2 {
    width: 62%;
  }
  .div_element {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id='div_1' class='div_element'>
    div 1
  </div>
  <div id='div_2' class='div_element'>
    div 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to set div width in above percentages?

Comment: 568px is a example width im mention, if size increases the both div size calculate the same percentage in main window size.

Comment: Then check my second solution please and tell me if you need more help.

Comment: var width = window.innerWidth;
c=(width/100)*38;
alert(c);

Comment: what you think about above code line? its calculate the percentage in script only, its right or wrong? im asking like this only. i know the css method to create above, bt i need to create in script only.

Comment: That's not the right solution that you mentioned.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. i get idea..

Comment: I think that Javascript and Css solutions aren't the same. The media query is a viewport measure ,window.innerWidth isn't (it's a browser viewport measure). For mobile browser where there are concepts as ideal and default viewport the difference should be meanful.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code to get browser window's height and width:

```
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need JS to do this when CSS itself can do so? This piece of code will maintain the div sizes on every screen size

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}
#div1 {
  width: 38%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
#div2 {
  width: 62%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
#divMain {
  clear: both;
  height:100%;
}
#divMain:after,
#divMain:before {
  display: table;
  content: '';
}
#divMain:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMain">
  <div id="div1">
  </div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```